# How can I search for old questions with recently active "interested users"?

Tags: support, search

If I want to search for old questions in need for an answer, I can use a search query like

```
is:question hasaccepted:no isanswered:no lastactive:6m.. score:1
```

but since I prefer to answer questions in which someone is actually *interested*, I would like to refine it to questions where either the OP or one of the users who favourited it has been active in the last $n$ days.

**Note:** I know that there is a way to search for questions within any *given* user's favourites, but I don't even know if it is possible to search for questions which have been favourited by at least $k$ persons.

Comment: Cannot be done via the built-in search; you'll need a SEDE query.

Comment: If you have a look at [SEDE database schema](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) you have `LastAccessDate` in the table `Users`. You also have `Posts.FavoriteCount`. Maybe you can use this to create your own query tailored for your needs. Or you can use some already existing query. For example, I found this: [Old unanswered questions whose asker is still around](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/36390/old-unanswered-questions-whose-asker-is-still-around).

Comment: If you plan to use SEDE for his, you should also be aware that the data in [data explorer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) are updated only once a week.

Comment: That said, favorites do not always mean "interested". I sometimes favorite a question when I'm out of delete votes for the day, to come back to it later.  Also, it would make sense to answer questions that **you** are interested in, something you enjoy working on. If a dozen people are dying to know the answer but you personally wouldn't enjoy solving that problem... why should you bother?

Comment: @pizza Of course I will then look through the results for a problem I would enjoy solving. This is meant to reduce the amount of questions I have to sort thorough to those that are in need of an answer someone is still interested in. I know that favourites don't necessarily mean "interested", but I think that's the best metric I have available. Plus, I don't think you keep those "to-be-deleted" stars around for six months or more, do you?